# No able to execute my feature file in intellij

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, webdriver-io

[I am working on new cucumber framework using webdriverio

When i try to execute a single feature it returns cannot find module

please help

i have tried to set path change the run configurations also

```
    'Feature:Launch Test

        Background: : user
        Given user launch the mi application


        Scenario Outline: remember me
        When user provides "<userName>" and "<Password>"
        When user clicks on remember me toggle
        When user clicks on login submit button
        When user clicks on account tab
        When user clicks on the logout
        Then application should remember the user
        Examples:
              |userName  |Password       |
              |abdasdada |tester01       |


    Testing started at 2:42 PM ...
    "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\MI_automation\react-native-automation\node_modules\wdio-cucumber-framework\node_modules\cucumber\bin\cucumber C:\MI_automation\react-native-automation\features\LoginTest.feature --format "..\..\..\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2018.1\plugins\CucumberJavaScript\lib\cucumberjs_formatter_v2.js" --format-options "{\"cucumberLibPath\": \"C:/MI_automation/react-native-automation/node_modules/wdio-cucumber-framework/node_modules/cucumber/lib\"}" --require C:/MI_automation/react-native-automation/features
    module.js:549
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'C:\MI_automation\react-native-automation\node_modules\wdio-cucumber-framework\node_modules\cucumber\bin\cucumber'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
        at bootstrap_node.js:609:3][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RruRY.png
```

Comment: Can you share your runner file.